# Oscillatory solutions if derivatives are are independent of each other?

Tags: dynamical-systems

Definition: An oscillatory solution is one where $(x(t), y(t))$ is a trajectory and $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are not constant. Further, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $x(t+nt) = x(t)$ and $y(t+nt) = y(t)$. $T$ is the period of oscillation.

Suppose we have a system

$$\dot{x} = f(x)$$
$$\dot{y} = g(y)$$

Further suppose $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ are both continuous and depend solely on their respective independent variables.

*Can this system produce an oscillatory solution as defined above?*

My initial thought is yes. If those derivatives can be configured such that they switch from positive to negative at favorable points, that should produce an oscillation as required above. But I can't seem to come up with a concrete $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ to prove it. Any ideas?

Comment: Should the $nt$ parts of the definition be $nT$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your system, the dynamics of $x$ and $y$ are not coupled. For a solution $(x(t),y(t))$ to be periodic in $t$, obviously both $x$ and $y$ need to be periodic. Therefore, it suffices to answer the question for the one-dimensional ODE $\dot{x} = f(x)$.

If $x(t)$ solves the ODE $\dot{x} = f(x)$ with $f$ continuous, $x(t)$ is at least continuously differentiable in $t$. Suppose $x_p(t)$ is periodic with period $T$, i.e. $x_p(0) = x_p(T)$. By the mean value theorem, we know that there is a time in between where $\dot{x}_p$ vanishes, i.e. there exists $t_* \in (0, T)$ such that $\dot{x}_p(t_*) = 0$.

Since $x_p$ is a solution of $\dot{x} = f(x)$, we know that the $x_p$-value at $t = t_*$ is a fixed point of $f$, because $\dot{x}_p(t_*) = 0 = f(x_p(t_*))$. However, we also know that the *constant* solution $x_c = x_p(t_*)$ solves the ODE $\dot{x} = f(x)$, because $\dot{x}_c = 0 = f(x_c)$.

To summarize, we have *two* solutions of the ODE $\dot{x} = f(x)$ which pass through the point $(t_*,x_p(t_*))$: the periodic solution $x_p(t)$ and the constant solution $x_c$. That's a bit of a strange situation, because that means that if we take $(t_*,x_p(t_*))$ as the initial condition for our ODE $\dot{x} = f(x)$, that we can make a choice between two trajectories. In other words, this would imply *non-uniqueness*. If $f$ is locally Lipschitz, then by the [Picard-Lindelöf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) theorem we know that this cannot happen, i.e. that $x_c$ and $x_p$ must be equal. So, if $f$ is locally Lipschitz, every periodic solution to $\dot{x} = f(x)$ is necessarily constant (and therefore not very exciting).

Interestingly enough, it turns out that you don't even need to assume that $f$ is locally Lipschitz to prove that nonconstant periodic solutions to $\dot{x} = f(x)$ do not exist. For more information, see @hardmath's answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52789/) question.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly not, since for an equation $x'=f(x)$ in dimension $1$ any periodic solution must be constant: otherwise the solution would pass successively on a given point but on different directions, and so $f(x)$ would have to be both positive and negative at that points (and so at many points).