# ODE - proof concept

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing

i need to show that doesn't exist f: R->R C1 class,
such that:

$\psi(t) = \cos(t), t \in \mathbb{R}$
is solution of:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x) \;\;\;\; (1) $

My attempt:

Suppose that exists $f:R\rightarrow R$, C1 class ; $\psi(t) = \cos(t)$ is solution of (1) that is:

$\frac{d\psi}{dt} = f(\psi(t)) $.

but note that: $\frac{d^2\psi}{dt} = \psi(t) = f'(\psi(t))*\psi\;'(t)$

so we got:

$\psi\;'(t) = \frac{\psi(t)}{f'(\psi\;(t))} \; ; f'(\psi\;(t)) \neq 0\; \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$

then $f$ is monotonically increasing or decreasing.

so here i'd like to find some contradiction but i can't. Perharps i took the wrong way.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that an autonomous ODE f(x)=x' has no nonconstant periodic solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52789/prove-that-an-autonomous-ode-fx-x-has-no-nonconstant-periodic-solutions).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof by contradiction that there are no periodic solutions to x˙=f(x)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2642530/proof-by-contradiction-that-there-are-no-periodic-solutions-to-dot-x-fx).