# Monotonic solution of first order ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be a continuous function. Let $x'(t)=f(x(t))$ be a maximal solution to the first order ODE. Show that the solution is a monotonic function.

This is the classical problem when you have the intuition, but you don't know how to write it down. My first idea was to show that if it's not monotonic, then you will have two points, say $a$ and $b$ with $x(a)=x(b)$ but $x'(a)> 0$, $x'(b)<0$.

Comment: I edited your post to replace the word "monotonous" with "monotonic" throughout.  This change, I believe, conforms with the most widely adopted conventions.  The word "monotonous" generally means repetitive or boring, which this question is certainly not.  ***Endorsed (+1).*** Cheers!

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Proof by contradiction that there are no periodic solutions to x˙=f(x)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2642530/proof-by-contradiction-that-there-are-no-periodic-solutions-to-dot-x-fx) and of [Prove that an autonomous ODE f(x)=x' has no nonconstant periodic solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52789/prove-that-an-autonomous-ode-fx-x-has-no-nonconstant-periodic-solutions).

Comment: I don't get why the two posts are equivalent.

Comment: @alexp9 The two posts are similar exactly because of the argument you mentions: If $x(t)$ was not monotonic, there would be points $a<b$ that $f(a)=f(b)$. (Note that the proof in the cited post only use the fact that periodic function would have the same value at two points.)

Answer (score 3):

I repeat then the proof given by Robert Israel as an answer to [Proof by contradiction that there are no periodic solutions to x˙=f(x)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2642530/proof-by-contradiction-that-there-are-no-periodic-solutions-to-dot-x-fx).  Suppose to the contrary that for some solution $x(\cdot)$ one has $x(a) = x(b)$ for some $a < b$.  Consider the integral
$$
\int\limits_{a}^{b} f(x(t)) x'(t) \, dt.
$$
On the one hand, as $x'(t) = f(x(t))$ for all $t \in [a,b]$, we have
$$
\int\limits_{a}^{b} f(x(t)) x'(t) \, dt = \int\limits_{a}^{b} (x'(t))^2 \, dt \ge 0.
$$
On the other hand, integrating by substitution we obtain
$$
\int\limits_{a}^{b} f(x(t)) x'(t) \, dt = \int\limits_{x(a)}^{x(b)} f(\xi) \, d\xi,
$$
which equals zero.  Therefore, $x' \equiv 0$ on $[a,b]$, so the solution is constant between $a$ and $b$.