# How to Prove that an autonomous ODE system ha no nonconstant periodic solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a function $A: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, and that $A$ is $C^2$ and the autonomous system of ODE's:

$$\dot{x} = -\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}(x, v)$$
$$\dot{v} = -\frac{\partial A}{\partial v}(x, v)$$

Show that this system has no nonconstant periodic solutions.

### My attempt

I was looking for materials in this stack exchange that could help me solve this, and I've found [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52789/prove-that-an-autonomous-ode-fx-x-has-no-nonconstant-periodic-solutions/52800#52800). It seems that my problem is the 2D generalization of the solution posted on that link. But I have no idea to work with what was posted in that link. Does anyone have any hint on the correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: In the contrary case, $a(t)=A(x(t),v(t))$ would be at the same time periodic and non-increasing. Which are (almost completely) contradicting properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience I'll define $\mathbf{x} = (x, v)$ so that the equation is $\dot{\mathbf{x}} = -\nabla A$. Now, since $\dot{\mathbf{x}}\cdot\nabla A = dA/dt$, we have that $dA/dt = -|\nabla A|^2$. In particular, this means $A(\mathbf{x}(t))$ is nonincreasing for any solution $\mathbf{x}(t)$. Since the only periodic functions that are nonincreasing are constant, a periodic solution must have $d A/dt = 0$ throughout. This means $|\nabla A|^2 = dA/dt = 0$ at all points of the solution, and thus $\dot{\mathbf{x}} = -\nabla A = 0$. So $\mathbf{x}$ itself is constant.